# Setting up a grid with vectors in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printGrid(const vector <vector <int> > &grid){
for (int row = 0; row < grid.size(); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < grid.at(row).size(); column++)
    {
        if (grid.at(row).at(column) == WALL)
        {
            printWall();
        }
        else if (grid.at(row).at(column) == COLOR)
        {
            printColor();
        }
        else
        {
            printEmpty();
        }
    }
}
}
```

For this function, I am to take in an input for grid and produce a grid with it like

```
xxxSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                 x
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
x                 x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxGxxxx
```

where S is the starting point and G is the ending point.

However, for my function, it output everything on to one line instead of making a nice grid.  How can I resolve this?  Thank you.

Edit:

```
const int EMPTY = 1;
const int WALL = 2;
const int COLOR = 3;
const int TO_BE_COLORED = 4;
```

the variables just give a color by using a different file.

Comment: Maybe print '\n' after the inner loop completion?

Comment: Could you upload source for other print functions?

Comment: Why do you say C in the title, but tag the question C++ and provide C++ source code?

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title to "How do I output a grid of vectors to stdout?" as your question is clearly concerned with output only.

Answer (score 1):

Print a `'\n'` after the last column of a row has been printed.